# How to use while loop to get answer (either yes or no) from users in Kotlin

Tags: if-statement, while-loop, kotlin

Greeting, You! I am learning Kotlin and I am struggling to use while loop to get answer from user. Not just that, if you could help explain how to use while loop to me, I would be really appreciate and thanks in advance.

[image: I want to use while loop then if-else statement]

Comment: Please post your code as text instead of an image.

Answer (score 0):

You should use while(ans == 'Y').
In condition checking you should make use of == to check equality 
And also in order to get repeated input put the readLine statement inside while loop.

Comment: Thank for answering :)